# To find the date when a threshold is reached in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to write a query in SQL that finds out what is the date when the X number of people have checked in. Records are tracking the person's name, Date checked in, and Date checked out (Null if not checked out).

For the following dataset, how do I know that I have reached the 3 patient-limit on 2/8?

```
    Name,      Date In,     Date Out
    John,     1/25/2014,     NULL
    Tom,      2/8/2014,    2/9/2014
    Joe,      1/21/2014,   1/22/2014
    Dave,     2/7/2014,      NULL
```

I have this query so far, but I don't know how to reduce the count number when the user has checked out

```
select count(c1.Name) as count, c2.DateIn
from customer c1 join customer c2 
on c1.DateIn <= c2.DateIn 
group by c2.DateIn
having count(c1.Name) >= 3
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you share desired output ?

Comment: Desired output should be just the date where the 3 users have checked in at the same time.  For this case, it would be 2/8/2014.  Would using a Stored Procedure be easier to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this:

```
select t1.*, 
     (select count(t2.name) from customer t2 
         where t2.date_in <= t1.date_in and (t2.date_out is null or t2.date_out >= t1.date_in))
     from customer t1
     order by t1.date_in
```

the new column shows how many users are logged on for every row in your customer table.

Comment: You got it right.  I am still trying to understand how you did it.  The t1 vs t2 comparison and what exactly is t1 and t2 is confusing me.  Thanks!

Comment: t1 and t2 are just alias names for the customer table ... t1 for the customer in the "outer" select and t2 for the "inner" select on the customer table

Comment: I guess the confusing part is, how do you know if you should use t1 or t2.  For example  "t2.date_out is null"--why not "t1.date_out is null"?  "t2.date_out >= t1.date_out" instead of "t1.date_out >= t2.date_out".  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Perfect By Design! :)

Comment: it seems you found a mistake there ... I didn't intent to use t1.date_out at all so no need to check for null there ... the subquery just tries to find all customers logged in (t2) when t1 loggs in

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly:

```
select date_in
from customer
where date_out is null
group by date_in
having count(*) >= 3
```

Comment: No, it does not return the correct date, in fact, it returns nothing.  This query only selects the users that have not left yet. It is not counting date when the middle 2 users was checked in.

Comment: This is my understanding: You want the checked in date (`select date_in`) on which 3 or more users have checked in (not checked out yet). As suggested above, if you give desired output then it will help to reply.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear.  Here it is:  I would like to what is the first date that there are 3 or more users have checked in.  It does not matter if that user leaves the next day.  For the example above, it should be on 2/8/2014.  Hope this make it clear to you.